# Get path of outputter

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to create a custom outputter on Azure Data Lake, but i can't find how to get the output file path. I want something like:

```
public override void Output(IRow input, IUnstructuredWriter output)
{
string path = ((FileStream)((Stream)(output.BaseStream))).Path;                 
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Jason's answer is correct. The path name(s) are provided by the TO clause in the OUTPUT statement. The Outputter writes into the IUnstructuredWriter and currently has no access to the name of the file it writes into. If you feel you have a use-case where you want to know the name and cannot pass it in as part of the rowset, please file a feature request at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think the output path to be part of the [TO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/output-statement-u-sql) clause, not part of the outputter itself. I don't believe the outputter would (or should) have visibility to it.